# universal linking (deeplinking) for unity IOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

Has anyone worked with unity deeplinking. I am following all the documentation and able to trigger the application using urlschemes or universal links. But my unity application is not able to receive the intents.

I even tried Application.absoluteurl but it still returns empty.

Some help here please.

Comment: can you post the your code and show us what you have tried? it's hard to help you without any basis.

Answer (score 1):

In Unity 2019.3 they have introduced Application.deepLinkingActivated and Application.AbsoluteURL which check if the app is opened using deeplink. The problem i had was a null exception. Once that was cleared the app worked.

Thanks for the suggestion guys.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is enter the application’s URL which need to open from your app in info.plist under URLSchemes.

```
url.scheme = “com.myApp”
url.host = “profile”
parameters = [ “user” : “Joy” ]
```

Then In appDelegate add this code:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL,   
options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
if let scheme = url.scheme,
scheme.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare("com.myApp") == .orderedSame,
let view = url.host {

var parameters: [String: String] = [ : ]
URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)?.queryItems?.forEach {
parameters[$0.name] = $0.value
}

redirect(to: view, with: parameters)
}
return true
}
```

Comment: I actually did that too. But my concern is in unity 2019.3 they have added this event - Application.deepLinkingActivated - which returns if the application is executed through deeplinking. That should work even without any modification in the appDelegate right?

Comment: Go through this link once.
https://connect.unity.com/p/deep-linking-on-android-ios-with-unity